# using $t0 versus $8 in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

Looking at various MIPS references, you can access a register using the common name or the register number. Are there any differences in the statements:

```
addi $t0, $t0, 1
addi $8, $8, 1
```

in addition,

```
addi $4, $t3, $zero
```

essentially just means $t2 = $t4, correct?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MIPS_Assembly/Register_File shows how the ABI names like `$t0` map to register numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. They are literally identical, yes.  Assemble and check the output binary if you want to be sure.  Example file:

   ```
       .globl f
   f:
       addi $t0, $t0, 1
       addi $8, $8, 1
   ```

   Then assemble and test:

   ```
   $ clang -c example.s
   $ objdump -D example.o
   example.o:     file format elf32-tradlittlemips


   Disassembly of section .text:

   00000000 <f>:
      0:   21080001    addi    t0,t0,1
      4:   21080001    addi    t0,t0,1
   ```

   Note that both encodings are identical (and get disassembled identically as a result).
2. Yes, `addi $4, $t3, $zero` is just putting the value from `$t3` into `$t4`.